# Availability of TotalView-ITCH data

Tags: market-data, tick-data, nasdaq, feed

I am looking for a cheap (< $500) NASDAQ TotalView-ITCH real-time streaming data feed.

Are there any cheap and (relatively) good market vendors out there that offer this? It seems as if the TotalView feed is rather difficult to come by as many vendors offer it only as an add-on to their own visualisation tool. I am looking specifically for the raw data feed itself.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, no, you won't find this.  The most basic one-port ITCH feed with no redistribution rights runs \$750/mo.  Historical ITCH data which is useful for backtesting is \$1,000/mo. with a 12 month initial minimum contract.  Fees for distributors are much, much more expensive (all costs can be found on the NASDAQ OMX website), and the restrictions on redistribution are quite prohibitive so no one can simply sublicense it cheap.